# Unable to merge dex after adding some dependencies

Tags: java, android, merge, dex

I am using ad-service Appodeal.
[Here](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1&platform=1) is installation FAQ.

I got error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

after adding to my gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Here is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hereismyappid"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'publicsuffixes.gz'
    }

}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation name: 'adcolony-sdk-3.2.1', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mmedia-6.4.0', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_alphab', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_appwall', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_appwallext', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_common', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_interstitial', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_mvdownloads', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_mvjscommon', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_mvnative', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_nativeex', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_offerwall', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_playercommon', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_reward', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_videocommon', ext: 'aar'
    implementation name: 'mobvista_videofeeds', ext: 'aar'
   // implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' -- error 
}
```

What i tried:

1. Clean & Rebuild
2. Delete .gradle

So what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

com.android.support:design:26.1.0 lib has dependecies:

```
1)com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0
2)com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
3)com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
4)com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
5)com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
6)com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0
```

You shouldn't add these libs twice. Remove duplicated dependencies and check /libs folder inside the project.